# Задача про кольцевой путь и неизвестное число вагонов

Tags: алгоритм

Есть кольцевой путь, на нем зацепленные в кольцо вагоны. В каждом вагоне может быть включен или выключен свет. Можно ходить из вагона в вагона и включать или выключать в нем свет. Вагонов может быть любое количество.

Как посчитать количество вагонов?

Comment: Оставляешь один вагон темным, бежишь по остальным и везде включаешь свет. Темный вагон - ограничитель в кольцевом списке. Дальше проходишь по всем светлым вагонам, пока не вернешься в темный, и считаешь. Начинать счет с темного.

Comment: Можно проще сделать за O(n): в одном вагоне сходить в туалет и обежать поезд до этой метки.

Comment: @typemoon, так не пойдет, до вас был я и начинал я со следующего вагона, поэтому добежите вы только до второго вагона ))

Comment: @typemoon, O(100*n) на самом деле это тоже O(n). В вашем варианте можно включить свет в выключенном на первом этапе вагоне и мы потеряли ограничитель. Решение "в лоб": вперед - включаем, назад - выключаем. Т.е. в первом вагоне включили свет, вернулись назад - выключили. Вернулись вперед к последнему посещенному вагону - включили свет, вернулись назад к последнему посещенному - выключили свет. Тогда на определенном шаге мы либо включим уже выключенный, либо выключим уже включенный. Это мы легко заметим, т.к. точно знаем где (не) должен гореть свет, а значит останется только подсчитать вагоны

Comment: @BOPOH Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, так вариацию моего коммента уже опубликовали. Там только по первому вагону ориентируются, а у меня "первый" каждый раз смещается. Если не ошибаюсь, мой вариант может на константу быстрее будет, а значит асимптотика все равно та же.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мы знаем какой свет горит в первом вагоне и всегда можем вернуться посмотреть не поменялся ли он. Переходим в следующий вагон и запоминаем сколько вагонов мы прошли. Меняем свет на противоположный первому или оставляем без изменений, если он уже таковым является. Смотрим первый вагон, поменялся ли свет. Если не поменялся, то идем дальше. Если поменялся, то число пройденных и есть ответ.

Cделал реализацию на **C#**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Carriage
    {
        public bool Light { get; set; }
        public Carriage(bool light)
        {
            Light = light;
        }
    }

    class Train
    {
        Carriage[] Carriages { get; set; }
        private int currentPos;

        public Train(int carriageNumber)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            Carriages = new Carriage[carriageNumber];
            currentPos = 0;
            Carriage carriage;

            for (int i = 0; i < carriageNumber; i++)
            {
                carriage = new Carriage(random.Next(2) == 1);
                Carriages[i] = carriage;
            }
        }

        public Carriage Current
        {
            get { return Carriages[currentPos]; }
        }

        public Carriage Next
        {
            get
            {
                currentPos++;
                if (currentPos >= Carriages.Count())
                    currentPos = 0;
                return Current;
            }
        }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter number of carriages: ");
            int carriageNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Train train = new Train(carriageNumber);

            train.Current.Light = true; //Включаю свет в первом вагоне.
            Carriage startCarriage = train.Current;
            int steps = 0;

            while (startCarriage.Light != false) //Всегда можно вернуться и посмотреть какой свет в вагоне с которого мы стартовали.
            {
                train.Next.Light = false;
                steps++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Number of carriages: " + steps);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```